# Is it possible to put a value that is not number on ylabel of morris.js charts?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, morris.js

[image]

I am trying to put a data that is not in number value on ykeys? is it possible?
I want to display on xkey the date, then on ykeys are price and product name, so i want to put the product name on ykeys of the chart? is it possible?

Comment: According to the "iPhone benchmarks" and "iOS device prices" example on morris.js github page, it seems to be possible, yes.

Comment: i tried on the benchmarks but the ykeys is number, and i cannot even put a php value on labels

Comment: [Look at the methods](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html) the docs describes and try them out, might help you.

Comment: yes, thank you and think now its not possible only digits

Comment: not even with `y-Labels`? Seems like the way to go.

Comment: can you please provide me an example?

Comment: @glendonphilippBaculio: So you want to have a literal value on the `y` axis? How could you read the chart then if values of the lines are numerical?